# Does the DVD commentary of the Babylon 5 movie "Thirdspace" have spoilers?

Tags: movie, babylon-5

If you watch the whole of *Babylon 5* in a popular suggested viewing [in answer to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/what-order-should-the-babylon-5-movies-and-series-be-watched-in) you watch the movie *Thirdspace* already in the middle of Season 4, even though it is made much later.

New viewers adapting that order are prepared for slight spoilers that have been deemed to not be important. But do the DVD **introduction to and commentary on** that movie contain further spoilers to coming events in S4 and S5?

Comment: I wouldn't *think* so, but I don't really remember the commentary that well.  Most commentaries are recorded long after series production completes though, so I'm curious why you singled this one out.

Comment: It's true that commentaries often are recorded long afterwards, and it happens that a commentary on an episode of a TV series contains spoilers for coming seasons. But most of the time they do not, and I think that commentators often take that into account..

What's different with this movie is that with the mentioned viewing order this is viewed long before its original place, and I don't think the idea of the currently most often recommended viewing order did exist back then.